# How to create AWS Lightsail instance from EC2 snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-lightsail

One of my AWS EC2 instances would be a better fit for Lightsail (and more cost-effective). Is there a way to create a Lightsail instance based from an EBS snapshot?

Comment: If it's not possible, I have had success with rsync of the entire drive using options -avhPHAXx [per this](https://superuser.com/a/709224) and then making a couple adjustments like reconfiguring the boot drive blkid in /etc/fstab (if necessary) and re-installing grub.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there is the ability to [Export Amazon Lightsail snapshots to Amazon EC2](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/amazon-lightsail-exporting-snapshots), but I couldn't see any capability to go from EC2 to Lightsail.

Looks like you'll need to reload/reconfigure a Lightsail instance from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the Lightsail-to-EC2 instructions, too. Just not the reverse. Seems like that's a deliberate act on AWS's part to keep people from making the sort of switch I'm intending (understandable, because they'd lose $$).

Comment: I don't think it's a profit motive ... it's just not a transition that they expect people to make.  Lightsail is a very basic VPS solution ... EC2 is much more flexible.  People would generally start with a basic option and move to the more flexible one.

Comment: The only real benefit that Lightsail has over EC2 is a bundled Data Transfer cost. Otherwise, it is an intentionally lesser-featured service that provides a simpler interface and fewer options, so as not to confuse its audience.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein IMO, simpler interface is a significant benefit. I'm an experienced software developer (30+ years experience) and find the EC2 interface quite daunting. I was able to spin up a few Lightsail instances that gave me everything I needed in a few minutes.